# Substituting NA's with data from other columns (and checking for reverse solution)

Tags: r

I have merged two datasets, one original data (x) and one reference (y). In some cases, the data has some missing values in particular columns, but in all cases, it is possible to retrieve this information from the reference. *Columns 1-4 are data, columns 5-8 reference.* So if have a (fictionalized) dataset that rougly looks like this:

### Input:

```
EFFECT_ALLELE.x NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x ALLELE1.x    ALLELE2.x EFFECT_ALLELE.y NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y ALLELE1.y    ALLELE2.y
1                I                   R       ATC            A               I                   R       ATC            A
2                D                   R         A     AAAAAAAC               D                   R         A     AAAAAAAC
3                D                   R         G         GATT               D                   R         G         GATT
4             <NA>                <NA>         T        TTTCG               I                   R         T        TTTCG
5             <NA>                <NA>         T           TG               I                   R        TG            T
6                D                   R         T        TGTTA               D                   R         T        TGTTA
7                D                   R         G       GTTAGT               D                   R         G       GTTAGT
```

I need a script that will detect where the first two columns are both NA, like line 4 and line 5 from the example above. Then it should check whether ALLELE1.x == ALLELE1.y and ALLELE2.x == ALLELE2.y, but only for the first three characters. If that requirement is fulfilled, it should replace the NA's in EFFECT_ALLELE.x and NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x with their respective equivalent from EFFECT_ALLELE.y and NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y.

### Desired output:

So, line 4 should be changed to:

```
EFFECT_ALLELE.x NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x ALLELE1.x    ALLELE2.x EFFECT_ALLELE.y NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y ALLELE1.y    ALLELE2.y
4             I                R         T        TTTCG               I                   R         T          TTTCG
```

Line 5 is a little different, because here the ALLELE1 and ALLLELE2 are reversed between x and y. Therefore, the substitution should also be **reversed**:

```
  EFFECT_ALLELE.x NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x ALLELE1.x    ALLELE2.x EFFECT_ALLELE.y NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y ALLELE1.y    ALLELE2.y
5             R               I         T           TG               I                   R        TG            T
```

### Working code (but too slow)

I have written a script myself that checks this for every line one-by-one. Not surprisingly, this is very slow. 
Checking 50 lines takes about 0.12 seconds, which would mean that checking the ~1 million lines I have in my file would simply not be feasible. 
It does work however, so here it is:

```
ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH <- 3
if (TRUE %in% is.na(data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x)){ #to make sure the script won't check lines if it is not necessary
 z <- 1
 for (z in seq(along=data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x))
 {
   if(is.na(data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z]) & 
      is.na(data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z]) & 
      !is.na(data$ALLELE1.x[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE2.x[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE1.y[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE2.y[z]) &
      (substr(data$ALLELE1.x[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE1.y[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH)) &
      (substr(data$ALLELE2.x[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE2.y[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH))){
     data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z] <- data$EFFECT_ALLELE.y[z]
     data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z] <- data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y[z]

     }   
 }  

 z <- 1
 for (z in seq(along=data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x))
 {
   if(is.na(data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z]) & 
      is.na(data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z]) & 
      !is.na(data$ALLELE1.x[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE2.x[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE1.y[z]) &
      !is.na(data$ALLELE2.y[z]) &
      (substr(data$ALLELE1.x[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE2.y[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH)) &
      (substr(data$ALLELE2.x[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE1.y[z],1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH))){
      data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z] <- data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y[z]
      data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x[z] <- data$EFFECT_ALLELE.y[z]


   }   
 }
 }
```

In summary:

- Replace NA's with values from same row in another column

  ```
  <NA><NA>  T  TTTCG   I   R T  TTTCG
  <NA><NA>  T  TG      I   R TG  T
  ```

to

```
    I R   T  TTTCG   I   R   T   TTTCG
    R I   T  TG      I   R   TG  T
```

- BUT: check whether this should be "reversed" or not
- Performance is an issue (would like to check ~1M lines in as little time as possible)

  Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated! And ofcourse, if this question has been asked before (I couldn't find it), I would also accept a link to that question as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
w<-which(is.na(data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x) & 
 is.na(data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x) & 
 !is.na(data$ALLELE1.x) &
 !is.na(data$ALLELE2.x) &
 !is.na(data$ALLELE1.y) &
 !is.na(data$ALLELE2.y) &
 (substr(data$ALLELE1.x,1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE2.y,1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH)) &
 (substr(data$ALLELE2.x,1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH) == substr(data$ALLELE1.y,1,ALLELE_CHECK_LENGTH)))
data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[w] <- data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y[w]
data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.x[w] <- data$EFFECT_ALLELE.y[w]
```

Comment: This gives me the indices of the rows that I need, but R gives a warning message for the last two lines: 




    __data$EFFECT_ALLELE.x[w] <- data$NON_EFFECT_ALLELE.y[w] 
Warning message: 
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, w, value = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated__ . However, if this would work, it would be a lot better than what I have right now.

Comment: Update: converting to as.character did the trick and it works now. I'm testing now if it's fast enough.

Comment: This works very fast (under 2 seconds for the whole file), and does seem to do the job very nicely (it still needed a second part, but that was no problem to produce with the code you provided). Thank you!